# SQL TRIM all values in specific field ( and variable set )

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, trim

Excuse me if I ask the obvious, but I am quite mySQL illiterate .

I am referring to a standard wordpress DB install, although this is not a wordpress specific question, but more mySQL general knowledge ..

If I want to change all the values of a certain field across all posts , I usually do :

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = replace(meta_value, 'old_value', 'new_value') WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'my_meta_key'
```

The problem is as follows :

In that specific DB , the INITIAL values were inserted with a white space prefix and suffix , e.g. :

```
"city name"
```

was actually inserted as

```
" city name "
```

of course , being a PHP person, I immediately thought of the `trim()` command - which I found out exists [also in mySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

SO now I thought I could just do

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = TRIM('meta_value') WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'my_meta_key'
```

But It is not working ..

What Am I doing wrong ? I know that mySQL is "ticks sensetive" ( so to speak ) But I tried both `'meta_value'` and `` `meta_value' `` ( sorry, markdown limitations seems to truncate the backticks)

Doing `replace(meta_value, ' ', '')` is dengaurous because some cities havea spaces in their name, and `LTRIM RTRIM` is somewhat not working for me as well

I also know there is a way to set a variable in sql ( `@my_var` )
but what is the correct syntax of doing that in my case ?

```
SET @my_var = `meta_value`
```

and then

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` TRIM(@my_var) WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'my_meta_key'
```

I of course know how to fix it in a php loop  (with trim() ) but I would like to learn what is the best way to do it in mySQL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the column, you need backticks:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
    SET `meta_value` = TRIM(`meta_value`)
    WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'my_meta_key';
```

Your expression `TRIM('meta_value')` is trimming the string `'meta_value'`, not the value in the column.

Comment: you dont need the `` at all do you ?

Comment: @Dagon . . . In fact, you don't.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I suspected that it was a backtick issue, but changing it ( like in original question ) did not seem to help. It seems that the phpMyAdmin which I am using is trimming the values itself, so when I check the values, they have no spaces .. even if in the real raw DB they do have it . ( intentional or bug ? ) anyhow, to be on the safe side if something goes wrong, is there also a `pad` function to revert ? ( I know it is not in the original question, But I could not find any ..)

Comment: @ObmerkKronen . . . There is not a "pad" per se, but you can do the same thing with something like `left(concat(col, space(100)), 100)`.